# UG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference

Tags: kernel

I have a problem with kernel, its seems i have a null pointer error, but i dont know how solve it, this is the message

```
[141065.223992] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at           (null)
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224272] IP: [<ffffffff8105ab12>] process_one_work+0x32/0x450
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224399] PGD 5a067 PUD 11e067 PMD 0 
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224404] Oops: 0000 [#1] PREEMPT SMP 
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224409] CPU 0 
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224410] Modules linked in: des_generic ecb md4 md5 nls_utf8 cifs vmsync(O) vmblock(O) mperf usb_storage joydev coretemp crc32c_intel ghash_clmulni_intel ppdev parport_pc shpchp pci_hotplug parport sg sr_mod mptctl vmw_balloon cdrom aesni_intel cryptd floppy aes_x86_64 pcspkr i2c_piix4 e1000 vmci(O) button ac container microcode autofs4 processor thermal_sys scsi_dh_hp_sw scsi_dh_emc scsi_dh_alua scsi_dh_rdac scsi_dh ata_generic mptspi mptscsih mptbase scsi_transport_spi ata_piix
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224448] 
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224451] Pid: 12951, comm: kworker/0:0 Tainted: G           O 3.4.6-2.10-desktop #1 VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224457] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff8105ab12>]  [<ffffffff8105ab12>] process_one_work+0x32/0x450
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224464] RSP: 0018:ffff880036419e50  EFLAGS: 00010802
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224466] RAX: 07fffc4001b2bdc2 RBX: ffff880036621c40 RCX: 0000000000000001
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224469] RDX: 001ffff10006caf7 RSI: ffff88003657b840 RDI: ffff880036621c40
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224472] RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: ffff8800bfc0d980 R09: ffffffff81c35f00
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224474] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 0000000000000002 R12: ffff880036621c60
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224477] R13: ffff880003726740 R14: ffff88003657b840 R15: ffff880003726740
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224481] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8800bfc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224484] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224487] CR2: 0000000000000000 CR3: 000000000010b000 CR4: 00000000000407f0
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224551] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224585] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224589] Process kworker/0:0 (pid: 12951, threadinfo ffff880036418000, task ffff880003726740)
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224591] Stack:
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224593]  ffff8800036ea240 ffff880003726740 0000000000000000 ffff880036621c40
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224598]  ffff8800bfc0d980 ffff880036621c60 ffff880003726740 ffff880003726740
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224602]  ffff880003726740 ffffffff8105b29d ffff880036419fd8 ffff880036419fd8
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224606] Call Trace:
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224618]  [<ffffffff8105b29d>] worker_thread+0x12d/0x2e0
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224627]  [<ffffffff81060a85>] kthread+0x85/0x90
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224635]  [<ffffffff81593c94>] kernel_thread_helper+0x4/0x10
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224640] Code: 41 55 41 54 55 31 ed 53 48 89 fb 48 83 ec 18 48 8b 06 48 89 c2 30 d2 a8 04 48 89 f0 48 0f 45 ea 48 89 f2 48 c1 e8 05 48 c1 ea 0b <4c> 8b 65 00 48 01 d0 83 e0 3f 49 8d 34 c4 48 8b 45 08 48 8b 56 
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224666] RIP  [<ffffffff8105ab12>] process_one_work+0x32/0x450
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224671]  RSP <ffff880036419e50>
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.224672] CR2: 0000000000000000
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.226667] ---[ end trace 819aa0342cc72bd4 ]---
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.226672] note: kworker/0:0[12951] exited with preempt_count 1
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.226804] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at fffffffffffffff8
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.226809] IP: [<ffffffff81060f67>] kthread_data+0x7/0x10
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.226817] PGD 1a0e067 PUD 1a0f067 PMD 0 
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.226822] Oops: 0000 [#2] PREEMPT SMP 
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.226827] CPU 0 
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.226829] Modules linked in: des_generic ecb md4 md5 nls_utf8 cifs vmsync(O) vmblock(O) mperf usb_storage joydev coretemp crc32c_intel ghash_clmulni_intel ppdev parport_pc shpchp pci_hotplug parport sg sr_mod mptctl vmw_balloon cdrom aesni_intel cryptd floppy aes_x86_64 pcspkr i2c_piix4 e1000 vmci(O) button ac container microcode autofs4 processor thermal_sys scsi_dh_hp_sw scsi_dh_emc scsi_dh_alua scsi_dh_rdac scsi_dh ata_generic mptspi mptscsih mptbase scsi_transport_spi ata_piix
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.226883] 
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.226887] Pid: 12951, comm: kworker/0:0 Tainted: G      D    O 3.4.6-2.10-desktop #1 VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.226895] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff81060f67>]  [<ffffffff81060f67>] kthread_data+0x7/0x10
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.226902] RSP: 0018:ffff880036419b30  EFLAGS: 00010002
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.226905] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000000
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.226908] RDX: ffffffff81c35f00 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffff880003726740
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.226912] RBP: ffff880036419ba8 R08: 0000000000989680 R09: ffffffff81c35f00
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.226915] R10: 0000000000000800 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff8800bfc12c80
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.226918] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff880003726730 R15: ffff880003726740
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.226922] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8800bfc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.226926] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.226929] CR2: fffffffffffffff8 CR3: 000000000010b000 CR4: 00000000000407f0
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227027] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227084] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227088] Process kworker/0:0 (pid: 12951, threadinfo ffff880036418000, task ffff880003726740)
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227091] Stack:
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227092]  ffffffff8105cad8 ffff880003726b48 ffffffff8158a522 ffff880003726740
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227096]  ffff880036419fd8 ffff880036419fd8 ffff880036419fd8 ffff880036419b68
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227100]  ffff880003726740 ffff880003726740 ffff880003726d5c 0000000000000000
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227104] Call Trace:
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227114]  [<ffffffff8105cad8>] wq_worker_sleeping+0x8/0x90
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227123]  [<ffffffff8158a522>] thread_return+0x275/0x453
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227132]  [<ffffffff81044537>] do_exit+0x5e7/0x950
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227139]  [<ffffffff8158cc89>] oops_end+0x99/0xe0
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227159]  [<ffffffff81580d58>] no_context+0x24e/0x279
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227166]  [<ffffffff8158ef05>] do_page_fault+0x3d5/0x490
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227173]  [<ffffffff8158c0b5>] page_fault+0x25/0x30
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227179]  [<ffffffff8105ab12>] process_one_work+0x32/0x450
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227185]  [<ffffffff8105b29d>] worker_thread+0x12d/0x2e0
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227192]  [<ffffffff81060a85>] kthread+0x85/0x90
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227197]  [<ffffffff81593c94>] kernel_thread_helper+0x4/0x10
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227201] Code: 00 00 83 a8 44 e0 ff ff 01 48 8b 80 38 e0 ff ff a8 08 0f 84 43 ff ff ff e8 37 98 52 00 e9 39 ff ff ff 66 90 48 8b 87 b0 03 00 00 <48> 8b 40 f8 c3 0f 1f 40 00 48 3b 3d f1 4e bd 00 74 0f 65 8b 04 
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227240] RIP  [<ffffffff81060f67>] kthread_data+0x7/0x10
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227246]  RSP <ffff880036419b30>
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227249] CR2: fffffffffffffff8
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227253] ---[ end trace 819aa0342cc72bd5 ]---
Nov 26 01:57:23 server kernel: [141065.227256] Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed!
Nov 26 01:57:51 server kernel: [141093.043458] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 23s! [cp:8017]
Nov 26 01:57:51 server kernel: [141093.044990] Modules linked in: des_generic ecb md4 md5 nls_utf8 cifs vmsync(O) vmblock(O) mperf usb_storage joydev coretemp crc32c_intel ghash_clmulni_intel ppdev parport_pc shpchp pci_hotplug parport sg sr_mod mptctl vmw_balloon cdrom aesni_intel cryptd floppy aes_x86_64 pcspkr i2c_piix4 e1000 vmci(O) button ac container microcode autofs4 processor thermal_sys scsi_dh_hp_sw scsi_dh_emc scsi_dh_alua scsi_dh_rdac scsi_dh ata_generic mptspi mptscsih mptbase scsi_transport_spi ata_piix
Nov 26 01:57:51 server kernel: [141093.048347] CPU 1 
Nov 26 01:57:51 server kernel: [141093.048357] Modules linked in: des_generic ecb md4 md5 nls_utf8 cifs vmsync(O) vmblock(O) mperf usb_storage joydev coretemp crc32c_intel ghash_clmulni_intel ppdev parport_pc shpchp pci_hotplug parport sg sr_mod mptctl vmw_balloon cdrom aesni_intel cryptd floppy aes_x86_64 pcspkr i2c_piix4 e1000 vmci(O) button ac container microcode autofs4 processor thermal_sys scsi_dh_hp_sw scsi_dh_emc scsi_dh_alua scsi_dh_rdac scsi_dh ata_generic mptspi mptscsih mptbase scsi_transport_spi ata_piix
Nov 26 01:57:51 server kernel: [141093.052390]
```

Comment: A NULL pointer dereference is basically a bug inside the kernel. There's not much you can do unless you're a kernel developer, besides using another kernel.